# How can I access resources from external website in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need to get picture from my Angular project (extrenally)
My pics are in the assets folder  `app/src/assets/pictures/picture.png`
and i want to get them like this  "http://monsite.com/data/picture.png"
so  `app/src/assets/pictures` ----> /data/
but with the routing pattenrs, it says `/data/` is not a valid route

(This is the goal I want to reach)

`[img]http://monsite.com/data/picture.png[/img]`

Do you know how can I manage to get this result?

Comment: Well, store the images in a directory named src/data instead of src/assets/pictures/, and configure the CLI to treat the data folder as an assets folder (look for "assets" in the angular.json file, and add an entry for the data folder). This has nothing to do with routing.

Comment: As far as I understood you want to download the image from an endpoint instead of having it in the `assets` folder, right?

Comment: Hi, where you use this image in the app component's Html or other's component's Html If you use in the app component's Html then the path should be " ../assets/pictures/picture.png "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `data` folder in `src` (`src/data`), then add the image `picture.png` in the `src/data` directory.

Now in order to use `data` as `assets` folder add the entry in `angular.json` assets.

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angulardemo": {
      "root": "",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/data" <- Add you custom asset folder here
            ],
```